# Laravel & paypal error tls

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I've tried to implement the Paypal API which works like a charm except when the payment occur :

Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

```
1/1
PayPalConnectionException in /home/epistol/PhpstormProjects/chorale_laravel/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php line 122:
error:141640B5:SSL routines:tls_construct_client_hello:no ciphers available
in PayPalHttpConnection.php line 122
at PayPalHttpConnection->execute('grant_type=client_credentials') in OAuthTokenCredential.php line 241
at OAuthTokenCredential->getToken(array('mode' => 'sandbox', 'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 1000, 'log.LogEnabled' => true, 'log.FileName' => '/home/epistol/PhpstormProjects/chorale_laravel/storage/logs/paypal.log', 'log.LogLevel' => 'ERROR'),
```

I do think it's TLS related but `php artisan serve` come with it, isn't it ?

Comment: It looks like you're requesting an unsupported cipher when the handshake takes place and the PayPal API is refusing to complete.

Comment: Okay, so, what can I do ?

Comment: Change the cipher to a supported one.